# CA error when create docker image with spring-native

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea, x509certificate, graalvm, spring-native

I'm trying to create my first "native java app" using spring-native. I modify my pom adding this

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.experimental</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-native</artifactId>
        <version>0.10.5</version>
    </dependency>
```

and this ( in the plugin part )

```
       <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <image>
                    <builder>paketobuildpacks/builder:tiny</builder>
                    <env>
                        <BP_NATIVE_IMAGE>true</BP_NATIVE_IMAGE>
                    </env>
                </image>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

If I run "mvn clean package" everythng works fine; but when I try "spring-boot:build-image" I get this error (the part of the picture that you can't see says "x509: certificate signed by unknown authority"):
[image]

I already tried to add to intellij the certs (image below) of the site but I get the same error.

[image]

Any suggestion?

Comment: If this is a certificate issue - the certificate must be added to the JDK which is specified in Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Maven | Runner | **JRE**. Also - have you tried executing this from the command line?

Comment: Hi @Andrey, i add the certificates to the cacert keystore of the jdk used by intellij, but I'm getting the same error. What do you mean with "have you tried executing this from the command line?" Bevasuse I tried to paste the url in the browser, and from the browser the downalod of the tar.gz starts correctly.

Answer (score 4):

The attempt to download from `https://github.com/graalvm/graalvm-ce-builds/releases` is happening inside a Docker container that runs the Cloud Native Buildpacks builder and buildpacks. Certificate errors like this can happen when the Docker container is behind a corporate HTTP proxy that uses custom CA certificates. There is a [Paketo buildpacks issue](https://github.com/paketo-buildpacks/bellsoft-liberica/issues/3) and a [Spring Boot issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/22220) that cover similar errors.

Adding certificates to a JDK trust store will not fix the issue. Certificates must be provided to the builder container when it is launched. This is covered in the [Paketo documentation](https://paketo.io/docs/howto/configuration/#ca-certificates) and in the [Spring Boot documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#build-image.customization), but it is a little difficult to understand exactly how to configure certificates.

As an example:

First create a `bindings` directory in the root of your project structure (at the same level as the project `src` directory) and copy the custom certificate to that directory (where `my-custom-certificate.crt` is a CA certificate in PEM format):

```
$ mkdir -p bindings/certificates
$ echo "ca-certificates" > bindings/certificates/type
$ cp /some/path/to/my-custom-certificate.crt bindings/certificates/my-custom-certificate.crt
$ tree bindings
bindings
├── certificates
│   ├── my-custom-certificate.crt
│   └── type
```

Then configure the Spring Boot Maven plugin to provide the binding to the Paketo CNB builder when the image is built:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <image>
        <builder>paketobuildpacks/builder:tiny</builder>
        <env>
          <BP_NATIVE_IMAGE>true</BP_NATIVE_IMAGE>
        </env>
        <bindings>
          <binding>${basedir}/bindings/certificates:/platform/bindings/ca-certificates</binding>
        </bindings>
      </image>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

Note that the `bindings` configuration of the Spring Boot Maven plugin requires Spring Boot version 2.5.0 or greater.